# Browse & Download Report files stored at Linux location with Pentaho CDE

Tags: linux, report, pentaho, pentaho-cde

Is there any functionality/Plugin in Pentaho CDE version which can help me to browse specific Linux location and provide download option for report files (3rd party reports) through my Dashboard screen.

please let me know, any possible option/example.
I checked Export component but that works with MySQL data reports and Charts in csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CDE has no such built-in plugin. As you can write JavaScript code in CDE dashboard then I think with small JavaScript code you can browse your Linux location and download file.

**or** you can use Pentaho CFR which will allow you to browse and download file from your linux PC.

[See this url to get full idea regarding CFR](https://community.hitachivantara.com/s/article/community-file-repository)

Comment: thanks Runa, but i am not able to build this plugin, ant dist-plugin ?, i didn't get this, please help me out

Comment: found plugin here https://marketplace.hitachivantara.com/pentaho/ , now i am facing issue in providing non- admin user permission browse access.. :(

Comment: figured it out with help of api i can provide permissions :)